# Can github boxen run in mac os 10.7 (Lion)

Tags: ruby, git, github, boxen

I am trying github.com's boxen tool in my mac os (10.7.5). However, every time I try to run the project template: https://github.com/boxen/our-boxen, it complains this:

`--> You must be running OS X 10.8 (Mountain Lion).`

Does that mean boxen tool can only run in Mountain Lion ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact that it's throwing an explicit error means somebody took the time to put it in place for anyone running it on OS's older than Mountain Lion.

There's very likely to be some symbols / API's in the source that are 10.8 only.  If you can find those API's and modify those methods to work on older OS's, then you'll have a 10.7 compatible version of Boxen and feel free to contribute your changes back to the community.  Be a part of the magic of open source software!